# Relationship between serviceworker and web push message

Tags: websocket, socket.io, service-worker, pusher, web-push

I am currently working on push notification in browser and I got stuck while handling push message. I am confused about how to relate push messages and service worker to receive the message and pop up in the browser.

I am somewhat clear with the idea of service worker but I am still confused how to relate this with push message and throw in the browser?
If anybody has clear idea about such project I am happy to hear it. I have my workflow diagram please go through it, if there is anything you can suggest by looking at this:
[image: Web Push Notification Workflow (wolfpusher)]

Answer (score 2):

Service worker works as a "daemon" inside the web browser, which receives new push messages from the Push Service and triggers desktop notifications for them. Here is a sequence diagram which explains the whole process:
[image]

For more details, read original [Push API specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/).